# NodaTime get Seconds from duration

Tags: nodatime

I have two instants, which represent an start and an end point in time.

I am subtracting them but want to get the seconds between these two points from the resulting duration, is this possible without trying to use the Period struct?

code:

```
Duration timeElapsedSinceLastNotification = SystemClock.Instance.Now.Minus(lastNotificationDispatchInstant);

//get seconds like so possible?
//timeElapsedSinceLastNotification.Seconds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 1.x, you can either do:

```
duration.Ticks / NodaConstants.TicksPerSecond
```

Or

```
duration.ToTimeSpan().TotalSeconds
```

Starting with 2.x (currently unstable) you have:

```
duration.TotalSeconds
```